# Do we need polkit and consolekit on our root-only servers?

Tags: debian, root

We have workstations where the only user is root. We use them only through ssh to distribute workload. We installed Debian 8 (Jessie) on those machines.

I've read that consolekit and policy kit are only used to register regular user shells and manage regular user privileged actions (e.g. freedesktop actions (shutdown)).

We don't have regular users, only root. These processes take a lot of space in `htop`.

Is it safe to remove polkit and consolekit ?

Answer (score 0):

Policykit is used for allowing unprivileged process to perform privileged operations without being root etc. In your case, your only user root will always be privileged.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late, but in general it is unsafe to run any serious machine with root as the only user. In this way anyone administering the machine could destroy it with an unintended command. This is why you should always create one or more less privileged (read: ordinary) users.

If needed these less privileged users could use the "sudo" command in order to execute tasks requiring root privileges.